# MediaCreator.CreateFromStream creates an item with the template "File"

Tags: media-library, pipelines, processing

I'm using `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreatorOptions` and `Sitecore.Resources.Media.MediaCreator` to programmatically create media items. I've set the `MediaCreatorOptions.FileBased` property to `false` yet the item created has the template `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/File`.

I assumed the item created would use the `/sitecore/templates/System/Media/Unversioned/Image` template.

Is there a way I can control the `MediaCreator` to create items with the `Image` template instead?

My code is executing from the `uiUpload` pipeline.

For reference, here is the code I'm using:

```
var mediaCreatorOptions = new MediaCreatorOptions
{
    Database = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("master"),
    Destination = item.Paths.Path + "/" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(mediaItem.MediaPath),
    IncludeExtensionInItemName = false,
    Language = Sitecore.Context.Language,
    Versioned = false,
    FileBased = false,
    AlternateText = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(mediaItem.MediaPath),
    OverwriteExisting = false
};


var creator = new MediaCreator();
MediaItem newMediaItem;

using (new SecurityDisabler())
{
    newMediaItem = creator.CreateFromStream(stream, "test filename", mediaCreatorOptions);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template used is dictated by the extension of the MediaCreatorOptions Destination.  Look for the mediaLibrary\mediaTypes config section and you'll see how the template you get per extension is configured

```
<mediaType name="JPEG image" extensions="jpg, jpeg, jpe, jfif">
    <mimeType>image/jpeg</mimeType>
    <forceDownload>false</forceDownload>
    <sharedTemplate>system/media/unversioned/jpeg</sharedTemplate>
    <versionedTemplate>system/media/versioned/jpeg</versionedTemplate>
```

As your destination has no extension it is using the "*" setting

```
<mediaType name="Any" extensions="*">
    <mimeType>application/octet-stream</mimeType>
    <forceDownload>true</forceDownload>
    <sharedTemplate>system/media/unversioned/file</sharedTemplate>
    <versionedTemplate>system/media/versioned/file</versionedTemplate>
```

You already have IncludeExtensionInItemName set to false so keep the extension in the Destination parameter so it knows what template to use.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that makes sense. I'm converting images to .webp in the uiUpload pipeline and hadn't added it as a mediaType yet. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `creator.CreateFromStream` selecting the template based on the `fileName` parameter. So you need add the extension to the `fileName` parameter like:

```
newMediaItem = creator.CreateFromStream(stream, "test filename.jpg", mediaCreatorOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! The second parameter wasn't very clear to me what it did. It says it's "filePath" in one place and "fileName" in another.